# State of a $ C^{*} $-algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $ (\pi,\mathcal{H}) $ be a non-degenerate $ * $-representation of a $ C^{*} $-algebra $ A $, and let $ h \in \mathcal{H} $ with $ \| h \| = 1 $. Define $ f_{h}: A \to \Bbb{C} $ by $ {f_{h}}(a) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \langle \pi(a) h | h \rangle $ for all $ a \in A $.

> **Question.** How can we show that $ f_{h} $ is a state?

We note that a linear functional $ \Phi: A \rightarrow \Bbb{C} $ is a state if:

- it is positive, i.e., $ \Phi(x^{*} x) \geq 0 $ for all $ x \in A $, and
- $ \| \Phi \| = 1 $.

Hence, we should prove that $ f_h(a^{*} a) \geq 0 $ for all $ a \in A $ and $ \| f_{h} \| = 1 $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a\in A$, $$\phi(a^*a) = \langle \pi(a^*a)h,h\rangle = ||\pi(a)h||^2\geq 0$$
Which shows that $\phi$ is a positive linear functional.
By theorem 3.3.3 of Murphy's C*-algebras and operator theory, if $\{u_i\}$ is approximate  unit of C*-algebra $A$, then $\|\phi\|=\lim \phi(u_i)$. Using this we have 
$$\|\phi\|=\lim \phi(u_i)=\langle \pi(u_i)h,h\rangle = \langle h,h\rangle = 1 $$
$\pi$ is non-degenerate $(\overline{(\pi(A)H)} = H) $, so for every $\xi\in H$, $a\in A$ we have $$\pi(u_i)\pi(a)\xi \to \pi(a)\xi$$ $\pi(A)H$ is dense in $H$ which implies that $$\pi(u_i)\to id ~~(\text  {sot})$$

Comment: For your last set of equalities, you need to use the fact that $\pi $ is non-degenerate.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: By assumption $\pi$ is non-degenerate.

Comment: Indeed, and your second  line of equalities wouldn't hold without it, but your answer does mention it, nor explains why.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I added the details. Hope it's sufficient.

Comment: Almost. It's  $\pi (u_i)\pi (a)\xi=\pi (u_ia)\xi $ and then you use the fact that $\pi $ is continuous.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Sorry, I do not know where I used the continuity of $\pi$. Please explain about it.

Comment: How do you show that $\pi (u_i)\to1$ sot?

Comment: @MartinArgerami: for every $\xi\in H$, $\pi(u_i)\xi\to \xi$. By the definition of sot convergence, we have $\pi \to 1$ (sot).

Comment: And why, for every $\xi\in H$, you have $\pi(u_i)\xi\to\xi$?

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Thanks, I found it. Continuity of $\pi$ implies that ${\pi(u_i)}$ is an approximate unit of $B(H)$.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  An approximate unit for  $B (H) $ would converge in norm to $1$. What happens is that $\pi $ is continuous, because all morphisms of C$^*$-algebras are; now for $a\in A $ and $\xi\in H $, $$\pi (u_i)\pi (a)\xi=\pi (u_ia)\xi\to\pi (a)\xi $$(because  $\pi (u_ia)\to\pi (a) $ in norm). Now you use the non-degeneracy of $\pi $ and an $\varepsilon /2$-argument to conclude that $\pi (u_i)\xi\to\xi $ for all $\xi\in H $.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: $\pi(u_i) $ is an approximate unit for $B(H)$, I mean $\pi(u_i) \to 1$ in norm.

Comment: No, that's almost never true. If it were, every Hilbert space would be finite-dimensional: you take $A=K (H) $, $\pi $ the identity, and so you are saying that $1$ is a limit of compacts, so compact.